# Code execution with sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, json, asynchronous

A variable is being set to `(null)` due to the `sendAsynchronousRequest` not completing before the request is complete. See code:

`main.m`:

```
GlobalSettings *globalsettings = [[GlobalSettings alloc] init];
NSString *url = [globalsettings facebookLink];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```

So, inside `GlobalSettings`:

```
-(NSString *)facebookLink
{
__block NSString *strReturn;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlEditedOut/"]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];
                           strReturn = json[@"FB"];
                       }];
return strReturn;
}
```

So this works fine, has been tested inside the `completion` block. However back in `main.m` the variable `url` is being set to `(null)` due to (i assume) the async request still connecting / processing request.

How do you combat this so that the variable is saved as the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

The url is set to null because the method returns immediately due to the asynchronous request. The way to avoid this is a delegate. make main the delegate of the GobalSettings and call the delegate method from the completion block. This SO-Post isnt an exact duplicate, but its close enough to get you started.
[How to return the ouput if method is using NSURLConnection Asynchronous calls with blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473077/how-to-return-the-ouput-if-method-is-using-nsurlconnection-asynchronous-calls-wi)

Avt's answer is what i would suggest, but returning a block works, too.